# How Do I Save A File With Hide X?

Tags: filemanager

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and Hide X 0.3. I've setup the library, and configured the database. How can I save a file
to it? I tried using:

```
hidex write +source="/home/myusername/file.zip" +wam=yes +destination="/home/myusername/file.zip"
```

I just got `error014291, error1, hidex cannot complete the request`. I've never used Hide X before so don't assume I know anything. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"error1" means your first **non-required** option is wrong. In this case that's WAM. Don't use WAM on .zip files because they are already compressed. Also you didn't put "" around the "yes" for WAM.

When using WAM you must provide a compression level. For example:

```
+wam="yes" +wamcompression="3"
```

A higher number means higher compression, but you will need a system powerful to implement the compression so don't pick a really big number. 0 means no compression.

"error014291" means you didn't provide your password. You have to provide your password using the `+password="password"` option. Given you are new to Hide X, I would also like to remind you that in order to use Hide X you must first login using `hidex login`.

Here is what you need to use:

```
hidex login
```

then

```
hidex write +source="/home/myusername/file.zip" +password="password" +destination="/home/myusername/file.zip"
```

Comment: This zip file isn't compressed. I tried with "yes" as you said for WAM, and the password, and it works.

Answer (score 5):

"error014291" means you didn't provide a password. I'm not sure what error1 is, but my guess would be you didn't login to Hide X first?

1. Login using `hidex login`. Enter your password when prompted.
2. Now type your commands with your password included.

   ```
   hidex write +source="/home/myusername/file.zip" +wam=yes +password="passwordhere" +destination="/home/myusername/file.zip"
   ```

Comment: I did login already, but you're right I forgot my password. The error other error persists.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't provide a password. Your password must be included EVERY time, unless you configure additional settings.

```
hidex write +source="/home/myusername/file.zip" +wam=yes +password="yourpasswordhere" +destination="/home/myusername/file.zip"
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds to me like you already have a file stored in "/home/myusername/" with the same name. Hide X won't overwrite files unless you add the `+overwrite="yes"` option. You do realize you don't **have** to use the same storage layout, I hope.