# How Do I Add A New File To Hide X's Library?

Tags: filemanager

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and Hide X 0.3. I've setup the library, and configured the database. I already asked
a [different question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522656/how-do-i-save-a-file-with-hide-x) about saving a file with Hide X, but I want to learn how to do some other basic things like this
too. I couldn't find any mention of doing this in the man, but I assume it can be done?

Comment: What exactly is `hidex`? What does it do and where can I find it?

Comment: @terdon It's a file manger that saves files to fake a storage drive. Website is hidex.oss .

Comment: @terdon I guess it's a fake: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8482/is-hide-x-a-real-product/8487

Comment: @SztupY yes, I've seen that post, that's precisely why I was asking. I don't see how quoting the post where you ask whether it is a real tool or not constitutes evidence that it's not though, so I thought I'd ask the OP who posted about it. Having seen his response and the answer you got on SU, it looks like this is indeed an existing, if probably defunct, tool.

Comment: @terdon: I wouldn't really call that answer as a proof of the tools existence, but even if it does I'd call these too localised

Comment: @SztupY my point was that your question is not proof of the opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, but you shouldn't ever need to unless you're using unstable file sources which is just silly.

First use:

```
hidex settings
```

which will enter the settings menu.

Press "8", which should be for modify the library.

Now use

```
hidex add +source="/home/yourusername/example.txt" +password="yourpassword" +length="100%"
```

which adds the file.

Lastly you need to refresh the libarary which means halting access first.

```
hidex halt +password="yourpassword"
```

Now that access is halted you need to restart it using

```
hidex start +password="yourpassword" +access="100%"
```

This will automatically refresh the library to include the new addition. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can, and when dealing with remote files it's often necessary to add or remove files. For example I use some files from Google, and have to supplement them regularly. It's true that it's not in the man, but you can use the command `hidex spill` to access the complete list.

Steps:

1. Type: `hidex settings`
2. Press "8" so that you can modify the library.
3. `hidex add +source="/path/to/file/example.txt" +password="password" +length="100%"`

Answer (score 4):

YES! You absolutely can add a new file to the library anytime you like.

`hidex settings`

Press "8" for modifying the library.

`hidex add +source="" +password=""`

There you go.

Answer (score 4):

No worries it's really easy, as far as Hide X goes that is.

1. Enter `hidex settings` to get into the settings.
2. Press the "8" key, so you can modify the library.
3. Use the below to add the file to the library:

   ```
   hidex add +source="/home/yourusername/example.txt" +password="yourpassword" +length="100%"
   ```
4. Now you need to refresh the library. The easiest way is just to reboot the computer.